# Морфемный состав "успокоишься"

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

*У/с/поко/ишь/ся* или *у/с/покоj/ишь/ся*? Есть ли фонетический йот?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *У/с/поко/и/шь/ся* или *у/с/покоj/и/шь/ся*?

Правильно: ***у/с/покоj***/ишь/**ся**.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли фонетический йот?

О, это сложный вопрос )))

На слух — неразличимо, смыслоразличительной функции не несет, но столько копий сломано из-за этого йота в интервокальной позиции — в мирных бы целях столько энергии.

Тут где-то было даже такое, что, дескать, все зависит от морфемного состава. (Если интересно — поищу, тут на форуме ссылки давали).

Спор ради спора, грубо говоря.

Моё мнение, что проще признать его существование, чем доказывать обратное.
Именно "проще", никак не "правильнее".

Доводы ЗА:

1. Действия закона "зияния гласных" (правильнее сказать — последовательного исключения такого зияния с праслявянских времен)
2. Последовательная фиксация этого йота, например, в украинском, современная орфография которого куда ближе к фонетической и практически заново создавалась в момент вполне развитого учения о фонетике.

Доводы ПРОТИВ:

1. Отсутствие какой-либо фонетической разницы между, например, **Луи** (Имя), в котором никакого исторического йота быть не может в принципе и **буи** (мн. к буй), где йот обязан быть исходя из морфемного принципа.
2. Необходимость применения дополнительных, не вызванных ни морфологией, ни базовой фонетикой признаков наличия дополнительной позиционной реализации аллофона йота.

На мой вкус, ЗА сильно перевешивает.

Comment: Вопрос интересен. А может как-то влиять присутствие йота в других словах с этим же корнем, ср.: *покой*, *у/с/покоj/ут/ся*?

Comment: @Aer, так это и есть то, о чем я писал. Попытка подвести фонетику под морфологию. Мне этот подход совершенно непонятен.  Можно (с грехом пополам) говорить **о нуле звука как позиционном аллофоне** некоего морфологически обусловленного йота. Но никак о наличии самого такого **звука** исключительно по морфологическим причинам. Признание, же того, что там есть йот **фонетический** снимает все вопросы.

Comment: ну, собственно, я так обтекаемо уточнил, нуль звука ли.

Comment: @Aer нуль звука - ну это хотя бы понятно с точки зрения внутренней непротиворечивости. Хотя, повторюсь, я всё равно считаю это избыточным наворотом. Куда проще признать, что он, йот этот, есть во всех подобных случаях, не только морфологически обоснованных. Ведь реально невозможно произнести, скажем, ии (Мар**ии**, п**ии**т) иначе чем **ие**  (гончие). В во втором случае йот этот есть. Даже если очень постараться произнести **ии** раздельно и в одном тоне, получится некий артикулярный затвор на границе двух одинаковых звуков. Почему не считать этот затвор аллофоном йота?